# explode function doesn't work in laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a Laravel ACL System. I have a User table, a role table and a permissions table. When I check the user given permissions using middleware and inside middleware I'm use `explode()` function. this function only show the first permissions other permissions doesn't contains.

Here, is my Controller;

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('HasPermission:Role-Read,Role-Update,Role-Delete');
}

My Middleware.

 public function handle($request, Closure $next,$permissions='')
{
    $permissions_array = explode(',', $permissions);
    dd($permissions_array);
    foreach($permissions_array as $permission){
        if(Auth::user()->hasPermission($permission)){
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    return redirect()->back();;
}
```

result when i use `dd()` function.

`array:1 [▼
  0 => "Role-Read"
]`

Comment: Try to explode with `-` symbol not with `,` Try this `$permissions_array = explode('-', $permissions);`

Comment: No,I have given permissions like this `'HasPermission:Role-Read,Role-Update,Role-Delete'` so, i need to the string like this `Role-Read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller

```
$this->middleware('HasPermission:Role-Read,Role-Update,Role-Delete');
```

Middleware
   Using ... to access variable arguments

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$permissions)
    {
        foreach($permissions_array as $permission){
            if(Auth::user()->hasPermission($permission)){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back();;
    }
```

or you can use

```
$this->middleware('HasPermission:Role-Read|Role-Update|Role-Delete');
```

Middleware

```
$permissions_array = explode('|', $permissions);
```